# Must return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus or take a completion handler as the second argument

Tags: ios, swift, media-player

This is what I do in my code:

```
commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pause))

@objc private func pause() {
    player?.pause()
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon-play")?.alwaysTemplate, for: .normal)
    delegate?.playerViewDidPause()
}
```

And this is error I get when I run the app:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unsupported action method signature. Must return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus or take a completion handler as the second argument.'

Answer (score 9):

You should change your method like this:

```
@objc private func pause() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
    player?.pause()
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon-play")?.alwaysTemplate, for: .normal)
    delegate?.playerViewDidPause()
    return .success
}
```

and everything will work like a charm